# Linux Memory Management

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

Is there any way i can mark a page execute only with no read permissions ? (i.e able to execute instructions on that page without having read permissions of that page which is executable.)

My final goal is to make a page that i can execute but no other process should be able to make any data access to that page ..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you plan to allow execute permissions without reading the page? I mean... you need to read instructions to execute them, right?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the things that is kernel and hardware-dependent, as mentioned in the [`mprotect()` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect):

> Whether PROT_EXEC has any effect different from PROT_READ is architecture and kernel version dependent.

On recent Linux/x86 kernels, those flags are definitely discrete if your CPU supports the [NX-bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit). On the other x86 CPUs, it depends on whether your kernel has support for [Exec-Shield](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_Shield) or another similar NX-bit emulation.